# Nested Loop running very slowly

Tags: perl, loops, nested

I'm trying to run a program to check each line of one file against each line of a second file to see if some of the elements match. Each file is around 200k lines.

What I've got so far looks like this;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#gffgenefind.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "SNP gff\n" unless @ARGV == 4;
open( my $snp, "<", $ARGV[0] ) or die "Can't open $:";
open( my $gff, "<", $ARGV[1] ) or die "can't open $:";
open( my $outg, ">", $ARGV[2] );
open( my $outs, ">", $ARGV[3] );
my $scaffold;
my $site;
my @snplines = <$snp>;
my @gfflines = <$gff>;
foreach my $snpline (@snplines) {
    my @arr = split( /\t/, $snpline );
    $scaffold = $arr[0];
    $site     = $arr[1];

    foreach my $line (@gfflines) {
        my @arr1 = split( /\t/, $line );
        if ( $arr1[3] <= $site and $site <= $arr1[4] and $arr1[0] eq $scaffold ) {
            print $outg "$line";
            print $outs "$snpline";
        }
    }
}
```

File 1 (snp) looks like this `scaffold_100  10689   A   C   A   0   0   0   0   0   0`
File 2 (gff) looks like this `scaffold_1    phytozomev10    gene    750912  765975  .   -   .   ID=Carubv10008059m.g.v1.0;Name=Carubv10008059m.g`

Essentially, I'm looking to see if the first values match and if the second value from snp is within the range defined on the second file (in this case `750912` to `765975`)

I've seen that nested loops are to be avoided, and was wondering if there's an alternative way for me to look through this data.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the scaffold_* key unique in any of the files?

Comment: No, there's many repeats of scaffold_* in each file. That would have made life easier!

Comment: If ``Python`` is ok i put my two cents in ...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - lose the `foreach` loop. That reads your whole file into memory, when you probably don't need to.

Try instead:

```
while ( my $snpline = <$snp> ) {
```

because it reads line by line.

Generally - mixing array indicies and named variables is also bad style.

The core problem will most likely be though because each line of your first file, you're cycling *all* of the second file.

Edit: Note - because 'scaffold' isn't unique, amended accordingly

This seems like a good place to use a hash. E.g.

```
my %sites; 

while ( <$snp> ) {
    my ( $scaffold, $site ) = split ( /\t/ );
    $sites{$site}{$scaffold}++ 
}

while ( <$gff> ) {
     my ( $name, $tmp1, $tmp2, $range_start, $range_end ) = split ( /\t/ );
     if ( $sites{$name} ) {
          foreach my $scaffold ( keys %{ $sites{$name} ) {
             if ( $scaffold > $range_start
              and $scaffold < $range_end ) { 
                  #do stuff with it;
                  print;
             }
          }
     }         
}
```

Hopefully you get the gist, even if it isn't specifically what you're after?

Comment: In this case, it seems that the split only creates as many values as are in the list on the left hand side of the operator. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Effectively, yes. You're assigning the array generated by 'split' to an array of named variables. Anything off the end is discarded. You could add `... ,$range_end, @everything_else ) = split ...` if you preferred.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see the way your code is working apart from the line `$sites{$site}{$scaffold}++` does this mean that you are giving the hash 2 keys?

Comment: Effectively, yes. You're using a nested hash - the 'outer' hash is keyed on `$site` and the inner hash is keyed on `$scaffold`. And the value held within is the number of times you see that combination (which may well be irrelevant). We iterate the `$site` list matching with your second file, and then we use keys to extract all the keys in that inner hash. (e.g. all the `$scaffold` values for that site).

Comment: In that case, if I am trying to do a comparison between the site (second value from the first file) and the range, would I reverse the way I key the first hash?

Comment: In that case, does it matter what exactly the value of `$sites{$site}{$scaffold}` is? It would be ideal to be able to print this value out as well and not just have it be the number of times I see a combination.

Comment: No - the only test my code does if 'is it true'. E.g. any value that isn't zero or a null string (or undefined). I usually use the '++' idiom for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `Python` snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import contextlib
if len(sys.argv) !=5:
   raise Exception('SNP gff')
snp, gff, outg, outs = sys.argv[1:]

gff_dict = {}
with open(gff) as gff_handler:
    for line in gff_handler:
        fields=line.split()
        try:
            gff_dict[fields[0]].append(fields[1:])
        except KeyError:
            gff_dict[fields[0]] = [fields[1:]]

with contextlib.nested(open(snp),
                       open(outs, 'w'),
                       open(outg, 'w')) as (snp_handler,
                                            outs_handler,
                                            outg_handler):
    for line_snp in snp_handler:
        fields=line_snp.split()
        key = fields[0]
        if key in gff_dict:
            for ele in gff_dict[key]:
                if ele[2] <= fields[1] <= ele[3]:
                    outs_handler.write(line_snp)
                    outg_handler.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(key,"\t".join(ele)))
```